# How to set table row overflow

Tags: html, css, html-table, overflow, tablerow

I have an html table with many columns. I need the table to fit in a (printable) page.

I figured I would allow the table row (tr) to overflow and take more than one row, such that each table row will actually be printed as two or three rows.

I know that it's possible to make each cell take more than one row, but that is not what I want. I want to have different cells of the same row appear one below the other.

Is that possible to achieve with css? I tried to play around with overflow properties of tr, but had no success.

Comment: I think this actually violates the concept of a table. You can use divs for that.

Comment: As it stands the question does not meet the guidelines here.  Please post your effort so far.

Comment: Rohit I tried, 'tr {line-break:loose;}'